# Downgrade from Monterey to Big Sur possible?

Tags: macos, big-sur, upgrade, monterey, downgrade

On my MacBook Pro 2013 I managed it to update from Big Sur to Monterey, although this notebook model was not supported for the upgrade. For that purpose I used the tool Open Core.
I regret the upgrade since macOS didn't get any improvement but instead it got some ugly glitches.
Can some tell me if there is a way to switch back to Big Sur version of MacOS?

Than you in advance!

Comment: There is no way to directly downgrade. Do you have a good backup made before the upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
Actually I'm aware that there's no direct way to downgrade. I'm much more asking for unsupported method to downgrade.

Comment: Then you're going to struggle. Any structure that has changed in the upgrade [this often happens to things like Mail] will not be directly re-importable to an older OS.

Comment: What do you mean by structure? The file system or something else?

Comment: The database structure. One Big Sur Mac here already has been through sufficient upgrades to have 4 different database structures, with some gaps due to missed upgrades or between different Mac generations/OSes - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQSLl.png These get migrated 'uphill' with each successive OS, but 'downhill' is not possible. I haven't seen Monterey yet, but if that's now v9, then you're out of luck. Golden Rule: always have a known-good backup before any upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
And is there a way to make a plain installation of Big Sur even hen all my data gets deleted? With Windows it's possible to re-install the OS. Isn't this possible with macOS?

Comment: Boot to Internet Recovery Cmd/Opt/R at the chimes. Wipe the disk & install.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133030/discussion-between-llasarov-and-tetsujin).